# Excel VBA - Function to show inputs needed and inputs used for a functioncall in a cell

Tags: excel, debugging, vba

I want a user-defined VBA function to get a better overview of inputs used for a bunch of different functions.

#### Example

Image I have the following function

```
Public Function simpleFunction(firstNumber As Integer, secondNumber As Integer) As Integer
    simpleFunction = firstNumber + secondNumber
End Function
```

Imagine also that I have a worksheet with `A1` equal `1` and `A2` equal `=simpleFunction(A1, 2)`.

#### Goal

I want to develop a function  `debugFunction`

```
Public Function debugFunction(inCell As Range) As Variant
    ' return a matrix with debug information
End Function
```

Letting `B1:D3` contain `={debugFunction(A2)}` I'd like a return like this

```
| Input name   | Input type | Input used |
-----------------------------------------
| firstNumber  | Integer    | 1          |
| secondNumber | Integer    | 2          |
```

#### What have I tried so far?

Not much since I'm really not sure how to do this proberly and I figure that I might come up with a not very clever solution compared to what is possible. But I do think that parsing `inCell.Formula` is the way to go.

#### EDIT

My ultimate goal is actually just what is showed in the *Function Arguments* window as seen here. I do realize that parsing the formula takes quite an effort and I do not want that. If there was some way to extract the info from the window mentioned, then I'd be happy.

[image]

Comment: To say this is "non-trivial" would be putting it mildly.  You would need to parse the VBA projects to find all of the UDFs, and then figure out how to handle all of the built-in Excel functions, and then figure out what to do with nested functions (like `=FOO(x, BAR(y, z))`), etc., etc.

Comment: A user defined function can only change its own cell so I do not believe you can achieve the effect you appear to seek. My trouble is I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If I have a complicated macro with lots of sub-functions, I have techniques for helping me debug the main macro and the sub-functions. If you are looking for ideas on debugging, I am happy to share some of my techniques.

Comment: @Comintern I guess you are right, but they might have been some _easy_ way (just a guess since the information is available in a GUI - see edited post)

Comment: @TonyDallimore I feel quite confident debugging functions. I am debugging whole worksheets, where I need a good overview of each function call in the spreadsheet. I hope my edited post elaborates a bit.

Comment: You can get to the *dialog* with `ActiveCell.FunctionWizard`, but it's a blocking call (and literally opens the dialog).

Comment: I have been thinking about your requirement. Consider a cell containing the formula `=SUM(B1:C1,E1,A,B)` where A is a named cell and B is a named range. `Application.Evaluate("SUM(B1:C1,E1,A,B)")` will return the value of the entire formula. You can also Evaluate "E1" and "A" to get the value of the referenced cells. But Evaluate "B1:C1" and "B" give `Type Error`. I do not think it would be too difficult to parse a complex formula into its components and to display them in a column.

Comment: With `On Error Resume Next` you should be able to step over the components that cannot be evaluated. It appears something close to what you seek is possible but will it help enough with debugging worksheets to be worth the effort.

Comment: @TonyDallimore that is quite easy indeed, but that is not really what I am looking for though. I am insterested in the definition of the arguments (name of the arguments and type if possible) for a function as well as its inputs used. The last part can be done (and I already have that) by your method, but not the first part.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx? I tried some of these routines years ago and successfully read the VBA code in a Excel 2003 workbook.  Might be worth a try.